# Styling a {@html...} tag of a Svelte component by ising the in-component <style> tag (Unused CSS selector)

Tags: css, svelte

I am trying to add some styling to an HTML tag rendered inside of the [`{@html...}`](https://svelte.dev/docs/special-tags#html) tag of a Svelte component, but it appears that it only inherits the parent's styling (the container of the `{@html...}` tag). Moreover, the "Unused CSS selector" error pops up displaying that my styling selector for that specific HTML tag inside of the Svelte `{@html...}` tag merely doesn't work. Is Svelte built that way and is there a method for styling tags that are rendered inside of the Svelte `{@html...}` tag?

I've tried steps provided in the official Svelte tutorial, but they don't clearly show how to do it.

```html
<style>
    p{
        color: red;
    }
    h1{
        color: blue;
    }
</style>

<script>
    let string = "<h1>what</h1>";   
</script>

<p>{@html string}</p>
<p>no</p>
```

I want the `h1` tag to be blue, not inherit the red color from the p tag

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to use the `:global(...)` modifier. If you do this...

```
:global(h1) { color: blue }
```

...it will apply to all `<h1>` elements on the page — both the one inside the `{@html ...}` tag and any that exist in other components.

To restrict it to elements inside this component, put the selector inside a local one:

```
p :global(h1) { color: blue }
```

That selector will only apply to `<h1>` elements inside `<p>` elements belonging to this component. [Here's a demo](https://svelte.dev/repl/705ffff723f74d58b8bef094c0338db1?version=3.5.1)

Comment: Is there a way to keep it scoped to the component?

Comment: @Arandomcoder The answer says "To restrict it to elements inside this component, put the selector inside a local one" and gives an example of that.

Comment: Global screws up external components

Answer (score 0):

It could be a bug (but it seems difficult for Svelte to know what could be there in that string).

As (an ugly) workaround, you may choose to specify required style inlined. For example,

```
<script>
    let string = `<h1 style="color:blue;">what</h1>`;   
</script>
```

**EDIT**: And Svelte [creator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2742396/rich-harris) has answered the official way is using `:global`.